# phpredis: got error when running script Call to undefined function new Redis()

Tags: php, redis, phpredis

## env:

- CentOS 6.5
- php5.5.3 / php-fpm5.5.3
- nginx 1.0.15
- php-redis 2.2.8

also added extension_dir and extension settings in php.ini

then restart the service of php-fpm & nginx

and i have confirmed the redis has been enabled/loaded in phpinfo()

## step:

i'm trying to run the php script like this

```
<?php
$redis = new Redis();
?>
```

got error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  new Redis() in /home/html/test1.php on line 2
```

but when i'm trying to run the same command in php Interactive shell mode, it works well.

why?

update:

i have test a script like this:

```
print_r(get_loaded_extensions());
```

then i got already loaded extension `redis`

```
if(class_exists('Redis')){
 echo 'Redis loaded';
 $redis = new Redis();
 }else{
 echo 'not function Redis';
 }
```

it shows class Redis exist but still get error

```
[root@i1 html]# php -f test1.php
 Redis loadedPHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function  new Redis() in /home/html/test1.php on line 16
```

add `dl("redis.so");` and the output:

```
PHP Warning:  Module 'redis' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Redis loadedPHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function  new Redis() in /home/html/test1.php on line 18
```

Comment: CLI and FPM can use different php.ini's. While one may include Redis, can other not include Redis. Make sure that Redis is loaded.

Comment: Yes - is there a `require` somewhere?

Comment: @CharlotteDunois thanks for your reply. and i confirmed they are using the same /etc/php.ini ... so any other tips for this issue?

Comment: @jcoppens i have update the description, could you help me, thanks a lot

Comment: use require_once("/path/to/Redis.php")

Comment: @user1735921 but there is only redis.so installed from php-redis extension. No Redis.php could be included/required... any way , thanks for your reply

Comment: make sure you have enabled it in your .conf file extension=redis.so;

Answer (score 0):

finally, i cant config to use the phpredis plugin.

predis is the better choice in this case.